# How do I solve this error in my code? NameError: name 'final_df' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

Building a machine learning a stock prediction model in python programming and it is giving me an error after running the program.
This is the code:

```
    #Import Libraries:
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas_datareader as data
    from keras.models import load_model
    import streamlit as st
    import yfinance as yf

    model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs =50)

    data_testing.head()
    data_training.head()

    past_100_days = data_training.tail(100)
    final_df = past_100_days.append(adata_testing, ignore_index = True)
    final_df.head()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
    NameError: name 'final_df' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you don't have a typo?
You assigning final_df to past_100_days.append(...) which is None.
That's weird, because None object doesn't have a head() method, that you are calling.
Maybe you wanted to make append first, then set final_df to past_100_days and than call head() like so:

```
    past_100_days = data_training.tail(100)
    past_100_days.append(adata_testing, ignore_index = True)
    final_df = past_100_days
    final_df.head()
```